# bound the expectation of max of sets of functions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

Let $X\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times d}$ be a random matrix, and $\{m_k\}_{k=1}^K, m_k \in \mathbb{R}^{d}$ be a fixed set of matrices. I was wondering, what is the expectation (or upper bound of the expectation) of

$\mathbb{E}\max_{k}\{||Xm_k||_2^2\}$

Any comment or hint will be appreciated!

Comment: For an upper bound, notice that $\|M_kX\|_2^2 \leq \|M_k\|^2\|X\|_2^2$ (where our first norm is the matrix norm), so $\max_k\{\|M_kX\|^2_2\} \leq \max_k\{\|M_k\|^2\}\|X\|_2^2$, and by the linearity of expectation, $\mathbb{E}\max_k\{\|M_kX\|_2^2\leq \max_k\{\|M_k\|^2\}\mathbb{E}\|X\|_2^2$.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I wrote my question in a wrong way (now corrected), but I think your method is still applicable. Thanks a lot!